# i am getting error while using NEW.id in database triggers

Tags: mysql, triggers

i am trying to create a trigger for inserting data.and I want to get the current id for that author or user who is inserting or change in table.but I am getting this error:

> unknown column id in new

here is my query

```
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(null,NEW.id,'inserted',NOW());
```

I have two table in my database `comments` table and `logs` table...

can anybody help me how can I get rid of this error...

Comment: Can you show the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE <tablename>` for the table this trigger is triggered by? I assume it's `comments` since you are inserting into `logs`. I wonder if `comments` actually has a column `id`.

Comment: I have created table comments and logs.. and I have created column in comments like comment_id,author,message and column or logs table are id,comment_id,action,created_date.. I want to create triggers on comments table whenever the table data is inserted in comments table it will automatically get id in logs table.. but I am facing this error: unknown column 'id' in 'NEW'. I want to associate trigger with this query.....INSERT INTO logs (comment_id,action,created_date) VALUES (NEW.id,'inserted',NOW());

Comment: It sounds like you _do not_ have a column `id` in your `comments` table. So `NEW.id` does not reference any column that exists.

Comment: should I need to replace comment_id with id in comments table and after that it will work fine ?

Comment: I would change the INSERT in your trigger to reference `NEW.comment_id` instead of `NEW.id`. The point is either way, the `NEW.<columnname>` must reference a column that exists in the comments table.

Comment: got your point... u saved my a lot time...

Comment: thanks akot for your response @BillKarwin

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your comments table has columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  comment_id ...
  author ...
  message ...
);
```

But your INSERT statement in the trigger references `NEW.id`. There is no `id` column in your comments table. The `NEW.*` syntax is a way to get access to the row that made the trigger execute. You can only reference columns that exist in that table.

So since I guess your primary key column is `comment_id`, you should drop the trigger and recreate it to run the INSERT like this:

```
INSERT INTO logs VALUES(null,NEW.comment_id,'inserted',NOW());
```

The point is that the `NEW.comment_id` must reference a column in the comments table, for which you defined the trigger.